# Can /ME endpoint be extended in SCIM

Tags: scim

When a user hits the `/Me` endpoint as per SCIM RFC 7644 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.11

the information returned is following

```
    "id": "<id>",
    "meta": {
    "resourceType": "User",
        "created": "<timestamp>",
        "lastModified": "<timestamp>",
        "location": "<url>"
    },
    "schemas": [
        "<value>"
    ],
    "userName": "Joe",
    "name": {
        "formatted": "Mr. Joe S Doe",
        "familyName": "Doe",
        "givenName": "Joe",
        "middleName": "S",
        "honorificPrefix": "Mr."
    },
    "displayName": "Joe"
}
```

Can we extend this `/Me` endpoint to get more information than id, userName, name, displayname which it is giving now? Will it be a violation of this endpoint as per SCIM standards?

Answer (score 0):

The first section of 3.11 says:

> A client MAY use a URL of the form "/Me" as a URI alias for
> the User or other resource associated with the currently
> authenticated subject for any SCIM operation.

I would interpret that as a yes to your question - you should treat this the same as a GET directly on the resource in question. GET on /Me should be treated the same as a GET on /Users/123 - assuming that your resource is a user and has an ID value of 123.